# Javascript HTML highlighter - text disappearing after 3 minutes

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, greasemonkey

I've been trying to write a greasemonkey script to highlight HTML text with a basic function. Below is where I'm at so far.

```
//Define highlightWordRed function
function highlightWordRed(word) {
var xpath = "//text()[contains(., '" + word + "')]";
var texts = document.evaluate(xpath, document.body, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (n = 0; n < texts.snapshotLength; n++) {
    var textNode = texts.snapshotItem(n);
    var p = textNode.parentNode;
    var a = [];
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    textNode.nodeValue.split(word).forEach(function(text, i) {
        var node;
        if (i) {
            node = document.createElement('span');
            node.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            node.style.color = 'white';
            node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word));
            frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        if (text.length) {
            frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        }
        return a;
    });
    p.replaceChild(frag, textNode);
  }
}

// Runs the script every 1000ms

function runInterval(){
  setInterval(searchThings, 1000);
}

function searchThings() {
    highlightWordRed("word_to_highlight");
}

runInterval();
```

So essentially at this point the script highlights the word properly, and runs on an interval properly. I'm running it on an interval to highlight contact that doesn't immediately show on pages (dropdown menus and such).

The problem being that after about 3 minutes, the text on the page disappears. It doesn't become unhighlighted, it just doesn't exist anymore and I can't figure out why.

Any advice on what to reaserch into or where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: I went in and tried to find what was actually disappearing in the DOM but couldn't replicate in Chrome. The deleting seems to only happen in Firefox.

Comment: Have you inspected the page using browser developer tools, to see what is actually changing in the DOM after 3 minutes?

Comment: I went in and tried to check but it keeps generating more and more span tags everytime I expand one. I suspect this isn't caused by my expanding but the script repetitiously selecting those,

Comment: What's the benefit of reinventing the wheel ([mark.js](https://markjs.io/))?

Comment: I would like to stick to as simple as a call as I can. While the code itself isn't very simple, I'd like to maintain the function("word") if possible. From what I've read with mark.js I haven't seen something that simple, or I haven't read far enough yet.